# Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. defined by $f(x)= n $ when $x\in(1/(n+1),1/n]$  and $f(0)=0$. Show that $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

My answer is, NO, it is  Riemann integrable because the function defined in closed bounded interval, So, if the set of all points when $f$ is discontinuous has measure zero. Then, $f$ is Riemann integrable in my example $f$ has countable many points which make $f$ is discontinuous. Am I wrong? Any help will appreciated

Comment: Did you mean $f(x) = 0$ for all the other points?

Comment: No, just on zero will be zero

Comment: It is defined because take $n=3$ as example so $f(x) =1$ when $x\in(1/2,1]$ and $f(x)=2$ when $x\in(1/3,1/2].

Comment: Yes, I answered below: that was posted by mistake

Comment: it has to be a **bounded** function on a compact interval s.t the sets of discontinuities have measure zero in order to conclude that it is Riemann integrable

Comment: Yes, thanks all, I forgot the bounded condition

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not integrable:
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n \cdot (\frac 1{n} - \frac 1{n+1}) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n \cdot (\frac 1{n(n+1)}) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{n+1} = \infty
$$

So, the integral diverges

Comment: Thank you, Could give me name for the book that  compute  the integral by series my text book does not have.

Comment: Gob, I just used the definition.